# CalendarStore API under 10.7 - duplicate calendars?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, osx-lion, icalendar

I have a simple app which creates tasks and events via the higher-level APIs Apple offers for iCal (CalCalendarStore, etc). In the past, when I pulled the list of calendars, it would display each one in the default CalendarStore just fine. However, in 10.7, it appears as if Apple has separated each local calendar into two separate objects: one for tasks and one for events.

If I have a user select a calendar, I need to make sure I use the appropriate task vs event objects accordingly, yet I see nothing in the docs (which haven't been updated in a while) about how to handle this.

Anyone out there already run into this?